# How do i create an edge list in for my graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

A 3 node graph `1, 2, 3` is represented by this data structure: `self.graph = {1: {2, 3}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {1, 2}}`.
How do i create a create an edge list for it ?

Comment: Which part do you not know? Show your code.

Comment: Can you give some more input? what you tried, and what you get or what your expectation ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using the graph package NetworkX.

```py
import networkx as nx
g = nx.from_dict_of_lists({1: {2, 3}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {1, 2}})
g.edges()
```

Yields:

```
EdgeView([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)])
```

Note that this treats your graph as undirected, so duplicate edges are removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {1: {2, 3}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {1, 2}}
e = [sorted([k,i]) for k,v in g.items() for i in v]
set(tuple(x) for x in e)
```

Output

```
{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)}
```

Comment: might be very compact, but isn't this rather inefficient?

Comment: Probably not, unless the graph is extremely large